# iPhone: Choosing an Ad Network?

Tags: iphone, ads

So I just released my app to the app store last friday. Realized it's going to be extremely difficult to get paid sales (but a good amount were downloading my app for free), so I decided to go with the model of releasing a full free version of my app with ads, and a paid version without ads.

My app has to do with adding captions to photos, so in two of my main screens, the app takes up the full screen of the phone. So I'm going to use full screen ads that pop up each time a user makes a view controller navigation transition.

I'm pretty clueless about how to go about choosing the right ad network. Right now I've installed Greystripe SDK and am playing around with it and it seems fine, but my one concern is that (I believe) they only serve Europe and North America. As an experiment, I made my app free and only half of the 150 or so downloads were from Europe and North America.

Was wondering if anyone could share some knowledge or link me to any beginner tutorials on how to choose an ad network. I've done google searches and haven't had much come up (maybe I'm using the wrong terms).

Comment: This is the rite place to ask this.

Comment: @IsaiahTurner - there a Stackoverflow on the stack exchange that would be better? When I looked at the list there wasn't really an obvious one.

Comment: Im saying you posted it in the rite place :) note the lack of the word 'not' lol

Comment: @IsaiahTurner - woops lol, minor details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've found in doing research on this, is that I'm shocked about how little information there is on this subject as compared to anything else in iPhone development. Not sure why this is, maybe because there aren't many developers using ads in their apps or maybe because the ones that do don't want to give away their secrets.

I think a good strategy for a newcomer for implementing ads is to start by using a mediation network. A mediation network is software that allows you to use multiple ad networks to serve ads to your app. So for instance, the mediation network will check to see if there is an ad to serve from Admob, and if there isn't it'll move onto the next network on your list. Doing this will give you high fill rates (i.e. making sure an ad is served the majority of the time when you call for an ad) and will also allow you to compare and contrast different networks. You can make adjustments in the mediation control panel without having to upload a new version of your app.

I also recommend starting out with some of the larger networks like Admob, iAds, Millennial, InMobi, etc. and then from there maybe branching out to other networks that do a good job in targeting specific things like video ads / interstitials, or certain countries.

So what I've done is gone with Admob Mediation for now, and am serving ads from Admob, Millennial, InMobi, and Adfonic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Try iAds](http://advertising.apple.com/)

[how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app](http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/)

Comment: unfortunately, iAds doesn't do full screen ads for the iPhone.

Comment: iAd will show as a small add banner at bottom..It will expand to full screen when you tap it.

Comment: Yeah I know, I need that type that shows up as full screen on arrival.